# How to pass JMX JVM options to Hadoop Mapper and Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

I'd like to turn on JMX for all my Hadoop mappers and reducers.

To do so, I need to add the following options as JVM options to the mapper/reducer JVMs:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

How can I do this from the Hadoop command line?

I know I can add JVM options to the mapper/reducer by adding:

`-D mapreduce.map.java.opts=<an option> -D mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=<an option>`

and that will pass `<an option>` to the JVMs.

How do I add the entire JMX options list from above. Will the following work?

```
-D mapreduce.map.java.opts="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" -D mapreduce.reduce.java.opts="<same as for map>"
```

I couldn't find any documentation or examples with helpful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you run the command from the question, it will add all the properties to the mapper/reducer JVM.